# How to show variable data for debugging in django

Tags: django, debugging

I still cant figure out, how to debug in django best way. For example, I created a dict and now I would like to check all the data that is arranged in that dict. How can I force django to show a debugging page in browser and print out the dict in a comfortable way?

Answer (score 3):

To get the variables value in browser using Django is possible naturally only if:

`DEBUG=True` is set for the app and some error occurs.

Instead you can use one of the following(if you already know the line/variables to debug):

1. `print(dict_var)`
2. From your view: `return HttpResponse(dict_var)`

Other way to debug is to use [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Add following line in your code to put a breakpoint and then debug line by line.

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

And run your app using

`python -m pdb manage.py runserver`

Comment: it's also worth mentioning to use a IDE with debugging features.

Answer (score 0):

**PyCharm**
You can use the debugger of PyCharm an ide developed by JetBrains.

It's free and it helps you in so many other way.
And if you are a student the premium version it's free.

[Download Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

**Edit:**
Then run the program in debug mode and set a breakpoint.
To set a breakpoint just click the number of line in the left of the view.

Comment: I am using pycharm, and how can I use it to see the content of a created dict?!